# Ruby dynamically create methods and variables

Tags: ruby, variables, dynamic, methods, instance

How can I replace add_entry method with something more sensible?

```
class MyStorageClass

    def add_entry key, value
        eval "(@#{key} ||= []) << value; def #{key}; @#{key}; end"
    end

end
```

So then I can retrieve value as follows:

```
def get_entry key
    begin
        self.send key.to_sym
    rescue NoMethodError
        nil
    end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than an instance variable per key, which requires some unnecessarily bulky code, why not just a single Hash like below. Also, `define_method` and `define_singleton_method` can be your friend to avoid bad bad `eval`s.

```
class MyStorageClass
  def initialize
    @data = {}
  end

  def add_entry(key, value)
    (@data[key] ||= []) << value
    define_singleton_method(key){ @data[key] }
  end

  def get_entry(key)
    @data.key?(key) or raise NoMethodError
    @data[key]
  end
end
```

You may want to check that you're not overriding a predefined method first (`!@data.key?(key) && self.respond_to?(key)` at the top of the `add_entry` method would do), but that's for another conversation. Could be bad if someone tried to add a key called `inspect`, `class`, or, oh, `get_entry`, for example!

Comment: You could also init @data with Hash.new { [] } so you don't need the ,||= part in add_entry method

Comment: Danger! It would have to be `Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = []}`, or else all new keys gain values linked to the others. The [] object you passed is a single object in memory that will be referenced by all keys, and the `<<` operator we are using modifies that object in place. Try it out! `h = Hash.new([]); h[:x] << 1; h[:y]` gives you `[1]`. I usually opt against the block initializer for Hash unless it's more beneficial than saving an `||=`

Comment: I did use the curly braces.

Comment: You did! Sorry, I'm blind. But that's worse, without the `h, k` arguments, because you aren't storing it in the hash object at all! `h = Hash.new{[]}; h[:x] << 1; h[:x]` gives `[]`

Comment: I suppose the danger still exists that someone confuses the curly braces for normal parens and the problem is perpetuated

Comment: From the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) "It is the block’s responsibility to store the value in the hash if required."

Comment: There's no need for your first line: "Edit:...". It's an unnecessary distraction. I would also put the boot to "IMO". Answers should not be opinions.

Comment: Edited. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using [`instance_variable_set`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_set) and [`attr_accessor`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor):

```
class MyStorageClass
  def add_entry(key, value)
    if respond_to?(key)
      key << value
    else
      instance_variable_set("@#{key}", [value])
      self.class.send(:attr_accessor, key)
    end
  end
end
```

**However** as others have suggested, a cleaner approach is to simply use a `Hash` rather than defining a new instance method for every variable.

Answer (score 1):

IMO this is a Really Bad Idea.  Do not do this!  You will be adding complexity with very little benefit.

I recommend instead an `OpenStruct`.  These are great objects -- you can call getters and setters on them at will without specifying the attributes in advance.  Perhaps a little inefficient, but that usually doesn't matter.

A side benefit of OpenStruct is that you can group your attributes into logical sets, e.g. connection_options, formatting_options, etc.  Here's a sample script to illustrate:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'ostruct'

class MyClass

  attr_reader :config_options # only if you want to expose this

  def initialize
    @config_options = OpenStruct.new
  end

  def do_something
    config_options.color = 'yellow'
    config_options.size = 'medium'
  end

  def to_s
    config_options.to_h.to_s
  end
end

my_class = MyClass.new
my_class.do_something
puts my_class  # outputs: {:color=>"yellow", :size=>"medium"}
```

Comment: @mudasobwa Context/elaboration, please?

Comment: I just wanted to drop a link to the great library, that is [IMHO] by all means a better equivalent of `OpenStruct`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you call “more sensible,” but here is the template without `eval`s to start with:

```
def add_entry key, value
  # define instance variable unless it is already defined
  instance_variable_set :"@#{key}", [] \
    unless instance_variable_defined? :"@#{key}"
  # add value to the array
  instance_variable_set :"@#{key}", instance_variable_get(:"@#{key}") + value
  # define getter
  self.class.send :define_method key { instance_variable_get :"@#{key}" } \
    unless self.class.instance_methods.include?(key)
end
```

The getter might be defined in more readable manner:

```
  self.class.send :attr_reader, key \
    unless self.class.instance_methods.include?(key)
```